# RxJava : Cannot invoke observe on a background thread when calling function that contains observer

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, rx-java2, searchview

I implemented RxJava/RxBinding in the `SearchView` that I created. here is the code

```
val queryStream = RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
 
queryStream.subscribe({
    if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
        Log.e("queryStream", "ini querynya ${it}")
        getSearchUser(it.toString())
    }
}, {
    // Exception
    Log.e("Exception", "${it.message}")
})
```

and here is the code for `getSearchUser()` function

```
private fun getSearchUser(q: String) {
    viewModel.getSearchUser(q).observe(this, { user ->
        if (user != null) {
            when (user) {
                is Resource.Loading -> binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    adapter.setData(user.data)
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.viewError.root.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.viewError.tvError.text =
                        user.message ?: getString(R.string.something_wrong)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

the problem is the `getSearchUser` function that is called inside `subscribe` block caused this error

`Exception: Cannot invoke observe on a background thread`

what should I do to fix this problem?

thank you

note: i use `jakewharton.rxbinding2` for the `SearchView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `.map` and changed  the order to

```
val queryStream = RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
    .map { query ->
        query.toString()
    }
    .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

and it works

but I still don't know how it works